# Polynomial Reduction and P

Tags: reductions, polynomial-time

Why w ∈ A if and only if f(w) ∈ B ? Which the signification of "if and only if" ?

Comment: Hint: if we require only that if $w\in A$ then $f(w)\in B$, show that you can reduce every language to every other language (except to $\emptyset$). Then, you get that such a definition is meaningless, since it provides almost no information about the language $A$ (or $B$).

Comment: Language A is mapping reducible to language B,
written A ≤m B, if there is a computable
function f:Σ* → Σ*, where for every w,
w ∈ A ⇔ f(w) ∈ B. Why  ⇔ ??

Comment: I understand the question. My hint above will guide you to understand why. If you're just looking for a direct answer, you won't gain any understanding. The answer is "because otherwise the definition is useless".

Comment: All element in A have to have an image in B ?I'm not able to understand the function reduction,exactly "if only if" !! Help me

Comment: Try to read [the answer here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10393/what-is-a-reduction-really). It also covers your question.

Comment: Why? Because that's the definition. "If and only if" is a standard piece of terminology. And please stick to one question per question.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.  If you have two questions, you can ask one, look at the answers, and then ask the other one separately.  I've edited your question to remove the second question, but you can look through the revision history (clicked on the "edited") to find it and ask it in a separate question -- but you'll need to flesh it out to show what self-study you've done, and what you've tried to answer it on your own.  We expect you to consult standard references before asking and to show us what you've tried and what your thoughts are.